# "Unable to Parse/Serialize body" in Kibana, ElasticSearch data populated with NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, kibana, nest, kibana-4

I have the following code in C# which works fine:

```
class Person {
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}


...Main()

    var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
        node,
        defaultIndex: "my-new-app"
    );
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {

        people.Add(new Person() { age = 1, id = i.ToString(), name = string.Format("Name: {0}", i), time = DateTime.Now });
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }

    var index = client.Index(people);
```

But then when I try to access my data in Kibana:

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

4. Error in JS Console:

[image]

Anybody have an idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Which Kibana/Elasticsearch versions are you using? I guess it's a compatibility issue.

Comment: Kibana 4.1.2 and ElasticSearch 1.7.3

Comment: Wrong guess. I can see in your screenshot "type`1"; the backquote in the middle may break JSON parsing. Can you change it in your C# code?

Comment: Could you show the whole body which can not be parse?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add each entry individually:

```
var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
    node,
    defaultIndex: "my-new-app"
);
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{

    Thread.Sleep(500);
    var index = client.Index(new Person() { age = 1, id = i.ToString(), name = string.Format("Name: {0}", i), time = DateTime.Now });
}
```